# How to create a dictionary of words with frequency of each word in php or python

Tags: php, python, file, dictionary, corpus

I have a large txt file `scrapped_db.txt` which contains over 100 Million words and size of the file is 1.7 GB. I created this file by using python scrapy framework to scrap a newspaper website.

Now I want to create a dictionary of UNIQUE words ( Bengali Alphabet, UTF8) each with its frequency(number of times the word appeared in the scrapped_db.txt file). Something like this

```
> আমি  201523
> 
> তুমি   15014 
> 
> ভালোবাসি  1233
> 
> দেখা 18556
```

or

```
> আমি  201523 , তুমি   15014 , ভালোবাসি  1233 , দেখা 18556
``
the dictionary should be another txt file. so that I can easily process the output file. 
One major PROBLEM is that, whenever I tried to use the file it shows several errors regarding file size. Please suggest a way in php or python.
```

Comment: "the dictionary should be another txt file" <- So you don't want a python dictionary, just a text file? Why? "it shows several errors" <- ok? Go on?

Comment: Use `Counter` from the `collections` module and read your file line by line. Afterwards save the result to a new file.  *Python solution

Comment: PHP or python? Tag spamming is usually frowned upon here

Comment: @timgeb : yes just a txt file.  I will use it as required.

Comment: @Random Dude would you please post the code , I am newbie. thank you.

Comment: @Andreas I don't get it ... PHP or Python means I can understand both PHP and python... I need any one solution between these two.

Comment: If you can write a custom Scrapy scraper, you can write this in about 5 minutes with a quick look at the docs. Getting the counts really is as simple as `counts = Counter(words)`. You can iterate it the same way you would any other dictionary, like, `for word, count in counts.items(): file.write(f'{word} {count}')`. There is nothing more to it.

Comment: @NahidHossain the answer from ThatBird is pretty much what i said.

Answer (score 1):

A python solution, as mentioned in comments, would work like -

```
from collections import Counter
word_count = Counter()
# Read File
with open("your_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split() # your words have to be separated by spaces for this to work as we need an iterable
        word_count.update(l)
```

With this you will get a dictionary like -

```
word_count = {'আমি': 201523, 'তুমি': 15014 ,'ভালোবাসি': 1233, 'দেখা': 18556}
```

Now all you need to do is write this dict in a file. You could just do `json.dumps(word_count)` on the file you are writing to. How to [read and write](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to a file in python.